# Handling ftp data in python

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I have a script that is pulling data from a file down from an ftp site using ftplib:

```
ftp.retrlines('RETR '+weatherfile,callback=handleData)
```

So I want to define handleData to deal with the data coming down, but I would like to be able to pass in additional args to that function.  So far, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.  The callback function is meant to take a single arg.  Is there a way to get it to handle more than 1, or is there a reason that I should avoid trying to do it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `lambda`?

```
ftp.retrlines('RETR ' + weatherfile,
              callback=lambda line: handleData(line, other_arg, another_arg))
```